# mysql insert 2 tables into another table use JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables:

table1:

```
+-----+-----+-------+
| ID  | num | title |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 101 |  0  | pro   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 102 |  0  | xtr   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 103 |  0  | low   |
+-----+-----+-------+
| 104 |  0  | hi    |
+-----+-----+-------+
```

and table2:

```
+-----+--------+
| Nn  | title  |
+-----+--------+
|  1  | ttl1   |
+-----+--------+
|  2  | ttl2   |
+-----+--------+
|  3  | ttl3   |
+-----+--------+
```

And I need mysql request to fill table 3 like:

```
+-----+-----+
| ID  | Nn  |
+-----+-----+
| 101 |  1  |
+-----+-----+
| 101 |  2  |
+-----+-----+
| 101 |  3  |
+-----+-----+
| 102 |  1  |
+-----+-----+
| 102 |  2  |
+-----+-----+
| 102 |  3  |
+-----+-----+
| 103 |  1  |
+-----+-----+
| 103 |  2  |
+-----+-----+
| 103 |  3  |
...
```

i.e. for each `ID` from `table1` I need all `Nn` from `table2`.

I wrote the following sql request, which works well, but I need the sql request  to use a JOIN statement, how can I do that?

```
INSERT INTO `table3` ( `ID`, `Nn` ) 
     SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t2`.`Nn` 
     FROM `table1` as `t1`, `table2` as `t2`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a [cross join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join):

```
INSERT INTO `table3` ( `ID`, `Nn` ) 
 SELECT `t1`.`ID`, `t2`.`Nn` 
 FROM `table1` as `t1` CROSS JOIN `table2` as `t2`;
```

Comment: as far as I understand cross is better in this case, because it's make all to all. And Inner is like cross, but inner join should use  condition

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t2.Nn
FROM table1 t1, table2 t2
INNER JOIN table3;
```

Comment: I'm glad that it helps to you :) and please considerate to mark it as accepted answer. Thank you!

Comment: You haven't actually added a JOIN statement between `table1` and `table2` here, you've just added `table3` to the mix, which assuming that 'table3` has no rows in initially, will return 0 rows.  If `table3` has multiple rows, you're creating a cross join across 3 tables now.  Not sure what you're aiming for here, it doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @TobyLL I'm not an expert of mysql, just a beginner but I let this answer because the OP saids that it worked for him. I wanted to put a condiiton but I couln't find anything to relate both tables. Thank you for your reply!